# Reusing of entites in symfony or Dynamic mapping of entities

Tags: php, symfony, mapping, entity

While Working on my project in Symfony, I realized that there is one entity(Assign Item to category) in my project which is being used in all other entities like products,categories,upsells etc as all of them need to be assigned to a category.

Is there a way that this entity can be reused?

I know a way where it can be defined in all ORM's (copy pasted in all entities), but want a more optimal solution to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're question is non-understandable, e.g. "where it can be defined in all ORM's" makes absolutely no sense in the context of your question. Remember, **often code says more than 1000 words.**

Answer (score 2):

After doing a research, here is what I found.
There is a term called dynamic binding in Symphony where one entity can be used into another there by saving us from writing the same code again and again.

Here is the link that helped me:
https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bundle with abstract classes that defines your entities. Don't forget to put there the annotations. Then load that bundle in your projects and extend your entities from these abstract classes. You can override methods or atributtes to customize to the certain usage. FosUserBundle works in that way

[FOSUserBundle usage](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)